# Remove space in marquee in html

Tags: html

I have created a marquee of images for my webpage. But how can the space between the last and the first image be removed to have a continuous effect ?? I am giving the code i used below,

```
<marquee style="overflow:" behavior="scroll" direction="left" OnMouseOver="this.stop()" OnMouseOut="this.start()">
   <img src="images/Bluelounge.gif" width="300" height="200" alt="lon">
   <img src="images/Southleather.gif" width="300" height="200" alt="south">
   <img src="images/Dell-monitor.gif" width="300" height="200" alt="monitor">
   <img src="images/Spphire.gif" width="300" height="200" alt="card">
</marquee>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add CSS rules to ensure that all spacing is removed between images within the marquee:

```
marquee img {border:none; padding:0; margin:0;}
```

Note:

The marquee element has been [obsoleted](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#the-marquee-element) in HTML 5.